# A question about the plastic number

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms, golden-ratio

The plastic number is well known to be the limiting ratio of the Padovan sequence (OEIS A000931), to wit,

$$
P_n=P_{n-2}+P_{n-3}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n}=p
$$

However, it is also the limiting ratio of the (unnamed) sequence (OEIS A003520)

$$
f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-5}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}=p
$$

So the question is, how does it come to pass that two sequences have the same limiting ratio? Are there any other such examples?

What I have done:

I speculate that the this is because the plastic number is a **morphic** number, which is defined as follows:

$q$ is a morphic number $\Leftrightarrow q-1={{q}^{-n}}\wedge q+1={{q}^{m}},\,m,n\in \mathbb{N},\,m>1,\,q>0.$

In fact, there are only two morphic numbers, the golden ratio and the plastic number. That is

$$
\varphi+1=\varphi^2\quad \varphi-1=\varphi^{-1}\\
p+1=p^3\quad p-1=\varphi^{-4}
$$

What distinguishes the plastic number from the golden ratio is that the morphic relations are different from each other, whereas for the golden the ratio they are the same.

Next I defined what I call the pseudomorphic numbers as those that satisfy only one of the morphic relations. These are denoted with the Greek letter chi, upper and lower case as follows:

$\chi$ is a pseudomorphic number $\Leftrightarrow \chi -1={{\chi }^{-n}},\,n\in \mathbb{N},\,n>0,\,\chi >0.$

$\text{X}$ is a pseudomorphic number $\Leftrightarrow \text{X} +1={{\text{X} }^{m}},\,m\in \mathbb{N},\,m>1,\,X >0.$

Next I demonstrated that all of the pseudomorphic numbers (which, of course, include the morphic numbers) are the limiting ratios of integer sequences, which were identified as follows:

For $\chi,\quad f_k=f_{k-1}+f_{k-1-n}$ (OEIS A000930 and related).

For $\text{X},\quad f_k=f_{k-m+1}+f_{k-m}$ (OEIS A103372 and related).

So, it can be seen here that the plastic number has two sequences, those for $m=3$ and $n=4$. You might wonder why the golden ratio, $m=2$ and $n=1$, does not have two sequences. However, you can readily determine that the two sequences are the same for these values of $m$ and $n$.

Of course, this is only an observation, not a proof. Can we prove that $p$ is the limiting ratio of two sequences and perhaps that this is a unique property?

FYI: I came to this question while examining the tiling properties of the pseudomorphic numbers, which I posted at the [Tiling List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tiling/eHG9RLpnr5k). You can find additional information there.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic Polynomials of the two recursions are:
$$
\eqalign{
  & z^{\,3}  - z - 1  \cr 
  & z^{\,5}  - z^{\,4}  - 1 = \left( {z^{\,2}  - z + 1} \right)\left( {z^{\,3}  - z - 1} \right) \cr} 
$$

Both have only one real root, which is positive and greater than $1$, and which is in fact the *plastic constant* $\rho$.
The asymptotic behaviour is therefore given by
$$
P_{\,n}  \approx f_{\,n}  \approx \rho ^{\,n} \quad \left| {\;n \to \infty } \right.
$$
and in particular the ratio of consecutive terms will tend to $\rho$
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {{P_{\,n + 1} } \over {P_{\,n} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {{f_{\,n + 1} } \over {f_{\,n} }} = \rho 
$$

Both have only one real root, which is positive and greater than $1$.
This will lead the asymptotic behaviour , and in particular will equal  the ratio of consecutive terms.

*-- additional note in reply to your comment --*

A [homogeneous linear recursion with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Roots_of_the_characteristic_polynomial) has an associated "characteristic polynomial" (see the above link for a wider explanation).
If the roots $\rho_1, \cdots , \rho_m$ of the characteristic polynomial are, to make it simple, distinct, then the solution to the recursion is given by
$$f_n = c_1 \rho_1^n +c_2 \rho_2^n + \cdots + c_m \rho_m^n$$
where the constants $c_k$ are determined by the initial conditions.
Then if $|\rho_1 | < |\rho_2 | <  \cdots < |\rho_{m-1}| < 1 < |\rho_m|$, clearly 
$$f_n \; \to \; c_m \rho_m ^n$$ as $n \to \infty$ and
$$\frac {f_{n+1}}{f_n} \; \to \rho_m$$
independently from the constants and thus from the initial conditions.

Therefore, all the solutions to linear homogeneous constant coefficients recursions which have the same *predominant* root $\rho_m$ will have the same asymptotic ratio, independently from the degree of the recursion and from the initial conditions.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but your equations are exactly equal to the two morphic equations. So there is no new information here. Am I missing something? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that, if the equations have the same leading root ($r$) of the characteristic polynomial, then $a(n) \approx r ^n$ and same $b(n) \approx r^n$

Comment: I expanded what was previously a hint: should be clear now.

Comment: @CyeWaldman: .. is it ?

Comment: The answer is yes and no. The yes is that I see they both have same root. The no part is that I don't know if this is unique or not. For example, can you find another sequence beside the Fibonacci that has the golden ratio as limiting ratio?

Comment: @CyeWaldman: For example ..yes, one amongst many: the [Lucas Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)

Comment: That's a trivial example because the Lucas numbers have the same recursion formula as the Fibonacci and differ only in the initial conditions. Hence the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @CyeWaldman: I added a wider elucidation: hope you get convinced.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. I feel as though we're going around in circles. Comparing the Lucas and Fibonacci sequences is not the same as comparing the two sequences that lead to the plastic number. So again, can you find another sequence beside the Fibonacci that has the golden ratio as limiting ratio?